# python Firestore OrderBy and Where conflict

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

```
docs = db.collection(u'scylla').where('status', '==', 0).order_by('last_time').limit(10).stream()
for doc in docs:
    print(doc.id, doc.get('last_time'))
```

[image]

[image]

#### Why doesn't it work when I create an index

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A terminal error is not enough information. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Is unclear to me if your issue is occurrinng after clicking on the provided link to create the index or if you are creating the indexes manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order_by('last_time')` is in ascending order so you need an index with ascending order for `last_time`:

```
scylla    status: ASC    last_time:ASC
```